# Excel VB runtime error 10004 unable to get the oleobject property of the worksheet class

Tags: vba, excel

One of the files I use stopped working. I now get the following error:

> Run time error 1004
>
> Unable to get the OLEObjects property of the Worksheet class.

I did some checking and it looks like the issue comes from this part.

```
Function GET_State_Is_Active_from_RadioButton_Control_by_Browser _
        ( _
            ByVal DetectedBrowser As String, _
            ByVal KPI_row1 As Long, _
            ByVal wb__Temp_Capture As Workbook, _
            ByVal tempWs As Worksheet _
        ) As Boolean

Dim str_Control_ID  As String
str_Control_ID = GET_Browser_based_Control_ID(DetectedBrowser, KPI_row1)

GET_State_Is_Active_from_RadioButton_Control_by_Browser = wb__Temp_Capture.Worksheets(tempWs.Name).OLEObjects(str_Control_ID).Object.Checked 

End Function
```

Problem is I have no idea what is wrong there. I admit my skills in VBA are limited and I am not the author of the file so I am having a bit of hard time making heads and tails out of it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this ?

Thank you very much for your time and help.